# How to Install Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3150 driver on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gpu-driver

Hi I am New comer to Unbuntu and after installing Ubuntu I see that My GMA has not drivers installed I searched everywhere but no results found how to install GMA drivers please help and also I am asking GMA drivers not Intel HD graphics.

Comment: The drivers are built into Ubuntu. You don't need to install additional 3rd party drivers for Intel GMA cards.

Comment: I see the graphics option and no name of driver is available please help

Comment: There's nothing you need to do, the driver is already built in.